can same table.cell get a value updated in realtime and then display "▲" or "▼" if the condition is met at barstate.isconfirmed in pinescript?

I want the fsr value to be updated in realtime and if the condition is met at candle close, then display the "▲" or "▼" in the same cell at candle close if condition is true.
I am using the following code to get the values: I have tried changing this to barstate.isconfirmed but it gives me out of bounds index errors.
the condition is correct as I have it in a separate column, but the "▲" or "▼" are not displaying the cell.
rsiNstochFun(tf, flg) =>
    [rsi, fsr, sv, lefv, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr_pivot_up, fsr_pivot_down] = request.security(symbol, tf, [RSI, FSR, SmoothVib, LeFV, GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, Is_FSR_Pivot_Up, Is_FSR_Pivot_Down])

    if flg and (barstate.isrealtime ? true : timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) <= timeframe.in_seconds(tf))
        array.push(tfArr, na(tf) ? timeframe.period : tf)
        array.push(rsiArr, rsi)
        array.push(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr, fsr_pivot_up)
        array.push(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr, fsr_pivot_down)

This is code for the table.
// Create the table
var table myTable = table.new(f_pos(PosTable), TABLE_COLUMNS, TABLE_ROWS + 1, frame_width=4, frame_color=#2F4F4F, border_width=2, border_color=#2F4F4F) // +1 for header row

// Set table header
if bar_index == 0
    for col = 0 to TABLE_COLUMNS - 1
        table.cell(myTable, col, 0, array.get(headerNames, col), text_color=color.white, bgcolor=#000000)

// Populate the table with data from arrays
for i = 0 to TABLE_ROWS - 1  // Loop through each row based on tfArr size
    values = array.new_string(TABLE_COLUMNS)
    valuesColors = array.new_color(TABLE_COLUMNS)
    array.set(values, 0, str.tostring(array.get(tfArr, i))) // Timeframe
    array.set(values, 1, str.tostring(array.get(rsiArr, i), "#.##")) // RSI
    array.set(values, 2, str.tostring(array.get(fsrArr, i), "#.##")) // FSR
    array.set(values, 3, str.tostring(array.get(svArr, i), "#.##")) // SmoothVib
    array.set(values, 4, str.tostring(array.get(lefvArr, i), "#.##")) // LeFV
    array.set(valuesColors, 5, array.get(bgArr, i)) // Background color

    // Check and set FSR Pivot Up
    if array.size(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr) > i
        array.set(values, 6, str.tostring(array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr, i))) // FSR Pivot Up
    else
        array.set(values, 6, "") // Default value or message if out of bounds

    // Check and set FSR Pivot Down
    if array.size(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr) > i
        array.set(values, 7, str.tostring(array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr, i))) // FSR Pivot Down
    else
        array.set(values, 7, "") // Default value or message if out of bounds

    // RSI conditions
    cond1 = (array.get(rsiArr,i)) >= rsi_ob
    cond2 = (array.get(rsiArr, i)) <= rsi_os
    cellRSI = cond1 ? #5D1616 : cond2 ? #194616 : not cond1 and not cond2 ? #000000 : na
    txtRSI  = cond1 ? #FF4500 : cond2 ? #00FF00 : not cond1 and not cond2 ? #FFFFFF : na

    // FSR conditions
    cond3 = (array.get(fsrArr,i)) >= fsr_ob
    cond4 = (array.get(fsrArr, i)) <= fsr_os
    cellFSR = cond3 ? #5D1616 : cond4 ? #194616 : not cond3 and not cond4 ? #1C1C1C : na
    txtFSR  = cond3 ? #FF4500 : cond4 ? #00FF00 : not cond3 and not cond4 ? #A9A9A9 : na

    // Smooth Vib conditions
    cond5 = (array.get(svArr,i)) >= SV_ob
    cond6 = (array.get(svArr, i)) <= SV_os
    cellSV = cond5 ? #5D1616 : cond6 ? #194616 : not cond5 and not cond6 ? #1C1C1C : na
    txtSV  = cond5 ? #FF4500 : cond6 ? #00FF00 : not cond5 and not cond6 ? #A9A9A9 : na

    // LeFV conditions
    cond7 = (array.get(lefvArr,i)) <= LeFV_A
    cond8 = (array.get(lefvArr, i)) >= LeFV_B
    cellLeFV = cond7 ? #5D1616 : cond8 ? #194616 : not cond7 and not cond8 ? #1C1C1C : na
    txtLeFV  = cond7 ? #FF4500 : cond8 ? #00FF00 : not cond7 and not cond8 ? #A9A9A9 : na

    // Populate table cells based on the split mode
    if split == "No" or (split == "Top Half" and i < 5) or (split == "Bottom Half" and i >= 5)
        table.cell(myTable, 0, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(tfArr, i)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)
        table.cell(myTable, 1, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(rsiArr, i),"#.#####"), text_color=txtRSI, bgcolor=cellRSI, text_size=Siz1Table)
        //table.cell(myTable, 2, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(fsrArr, i),"#.#####"), text_color = txtFSR, bgcolor=cellFSR, text_size=Siz1Table)
        table.cell(myTable, 3, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(svArr, i),"#.#####"), text_color = txtSV, bgcolor=cellSV, text_size=Siz1Table)
        table.cell(myTable, 4, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(lefvArr, i),"#.#####"), text_color = txtLeFV, bgcolor=cellLeFV, text_size=Siz1Table)
        table.cell(myTable, 5, i + 1, "", bgcolor=array.get(bgArr, i))
        table.cell(myTable, 6, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr, i)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)
        table.cell(myTable, 7, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr, i)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor=#000000, text_size=Siz1Table)

// Confirmed bar logic
if barstate.isconfirmed 
    for i = 0 to TABLE_ROWS - 1
        // Ensure arrays have enough values
        if array.size(fsrArr) > i and array.size(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr) > i and array.size(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr) > i
            // FSR conditions
            cond3 = (array.get(fsrArr, i)) >= fsr_ob
            cond4 = (array.get(fsrArr, i)) <= fsr_os
            cellFSR = cond3 ? #5D1616 : cond4 ? #194616 : not cond3 and not cond4 ? #1C1C1C : na
            txtFSR  = cond3 ? #FF4500 : cond4 ? #00FF00 : not cond3 and not cond4 ? #A9A9A9 : na

            var string SIGNAL = ""

            // Handle the FSR pivot signals
            if array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Up_arr, i) == 1
                SIGNAL := "▲"
            else if array.get(Is_FSR_Pivot_Down_arr, i) == 1
                SIGNAL := "▼"

            // Concatenate the FSR value and the SIGNAL symbol
            FSR_with_SIGNAL = str.tostring(array.get(fsrArr, i), "#.#####") + " " + SIGNAL

            // Print FSR_with_SIGNAL to check its value
            //label.new(bar_index, high, text=FSR_with_SIGNAL, style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, size=size.small)

            // Populate the table with the values and the signal
            if split == "No" or (split == "Top Half" and i < 5) or (split == "Bottom Half" and i >= 5)
                table.cell(myTable, 2, i + 1, FSR_with_SIGNAL, text_color = txtFSR, bgcolor=cellFSR, text_size=Siz1Table)

